# Find a function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that is absolutely continuous on $[\epsilon,1]$ for each $\epsilon>0$ but not on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Give an example of a function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that is absolutely continuous on $[\epsilon,1]$ for each $\epsilon>0$ but not absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$.

I'm thinking $f(x)= \frac{\epsilon+1}{x+1}$ but I'm getting nowhere trying to figure out what $\delta$ is in terms of $\epsilon$ to show that it is absolutely continuous. Will that function actually work? If so, how can I prove it does?

Comment: That one will not work, because it's not defined on all of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Your function is supposed to depend solely on $x$, not on $\epsilon$, otherwise you are talking about a family of functions.

Comment: Do you mean for f to be continuous on [0,1]?

Answer (score 4):

Try $f(x) = 1/x,x\in (0,1], f(0) = 0.$

Comment: That's what I was thinking originally. I can't remember now why I dismissed that idea, but it brings me to the second part of my question. How do I pick the appropriate $\delta$ for any given $\epsilon$ to show it is absolutely continuous?

Comment: uniformly continuous?

Comment: sorry, I'm working on a uniform convergence problem too and mixed up the words.

Comment: Any function with bounded derivative on an interval is absolutely continuous there (by the MVT).

Comment: But $\frac{1}{x}$ does not have a bounded derivative on $(0,1]$??

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom But it has a bounded derivative on  each $[\epsilon,1],$ $0<\epsilon <1.$

Answer (score 3):

Let 
$g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$g(x) = \begin{cases} 
      \ 1  \textrm{ if $x=0$} \\
       \ 0  \textrm{ otherwise} \\
   \end{cases}$

Then $g$ is not even continuous on $[0,1]$ but is clearly absolutely continuous for all $x \in (0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be any continuous function on $(0,1]$ with a discontinuity at $x=0$. It is known that a continuous function on a closed interval is uniformly continuous (for an elementary proof, see Michael Spivak's "Calculus" book). Therefore, $f$ will be uniformly continuous on every interval $[\varepsilon,1]$ with $\varepsilon>0$, but $f$ is not even continuous on $[0,1]$, so it cannot be uniformly continuous on such interval. Examples of such functions were given in previous answers.